# Reading only two characters before a specific pattern in a linux file

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I have a file like

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on 
/abc/xyz/mnop          
                       82G  7.7G   70G  10% /  
hello                  32G  922M   31G   3% /abc/asd 
/abc/xyz              477M  118M  334M  27% /asd   
/abc/xyz               50G  9.4G   38G  21% /ad  
/abc/xyz               79G   27G   49G  36% /asd   
/abc/xyz               30G  7.9G   21G  29% /sd  
/abc/xyz              197G  2.4G  185G   2% /asd  
xyz:/backups/abc      
                      500G   18G  483G   4% /asdas  
abc                   
                      1.9T  1.5T  405G  79% /media/Scratch
```

I want only the two characters before % i.e 10,3,27,21 and so on which i will compare one by one with a value 85 whether greater or less. But the first line use% should be skipped. Please suggest me how to get only those values in a variable one by one or in a file which i can compare with 85 using conditional statements.

i used **grep -E -o ".{0,2}%" test.txt** , but it is giving % with the values e.g 10% and also se% which i don't want.

Thanks

Comment: Is it output of `du -h`?

Comment: df -kh from many servers which i am taking one by one using loop in a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
df -h | awk 'NR>1{print $5+0}'
```

Or with a file:

```
awk 'NR>1{print $5+0}' test.txt
```

Using `gnu grep`:

```
grep -oP '\d+(?=%)' test.txt
```

Comment: Thanks anubhava but the output is irregular ,it's giving like
0
0
3
27
21
36
29
2
0
0
0
0

Comment: Try this: `grep -oP '\d+(?=%)' test.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Use perl: perl -ne 'print $1 . "," if /(\d{1,2})\%/' test.txt

Comment: Thanks , but those all comes in a single line like 103272136292479, i want them either separated via a delimiter or in next lines. Can you suggest that.

Comment: perl -ne 'print $1 . "," if /(\d{1,2})\%/' test.txt

Answer (score 0):

Use below command it helps to get your desired results

```
cat text.txt | cut -d'%' -f1 | awk '{print $NF }'
```

Comment: hi , please see my input file again made little modifications, from your command  i am getting output like 
Use
/abc/xyz/mnop 
10
3
27
21
36
29
2
xyz:/backups/abc  
4
abc       
79

Comment: You can alter the above  command as below.                                                         cat text.txt | cut -d'%' -f1 | awk '{ if (NF > 1 ) print $NF  }'